# How to hide password text in an editbox for office ribbon development

Tags: c#, excel, ribbon, editbox

I am making an application using visual studio and I am making an Excel Addon.
I would like to add a username and password field so I am using Editbox to do this however there doesnt seem to be a passwordChar field.

What could I use instead or how can I hide the text?

I am currently trying to convert the chars to * but its very slow.
Im also working in C#

This is my current solution:

```
private void ebxPassword_KeyUp(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    char last = ebxPassword.Text[ebxPassword.Text.Length - 1];
    passwordText += last;
    ebxPassword.Text = ebxPassword.Text.Replace(last.ToString(), "*");
}
```

My Final Solution:

It cannot be done, there is no simple way around it.
So instead of having these controls in the ribbon, I added a login button and when clicked loads a form with a standard text box and this works perfectly fine.

Comment: Posting your code will give more clarity about the problem.

Comment: @Junaith added some code

Comment: Is it Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.EditBox?

Comment: yea that is what i am using

Comment: I thought its TextBox. I have to read the question carefully. Have you tried the [PasswordEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.editbox.passwordedit%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property

Comment: No how would i make use of that property?

Comment: @BrianPeach How did you wire up this event to the ribbon? IE -what event property did you use?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for Late answer..Answered for whom check this question to hope to find a solution in future..

With this extension method which i use in my projects when needed..No matter where it called..just string is enough ;) here the solution :

```
public static string Mask_IT(this string source, char MaskingChar, int AllowedCharCount)
  {
     var cArr = source.ToCharArray();

     if(source.Length - AllowedCharCount >=0)
     {

         for (int i = 0; i < ( cArr.Length - AllowedCharCount; i++ )
         {
          if (cArr[i] != MaskingChar) cArr[i] = MaskingChar;
         }
     }

         return cArr.ToString();
  }
```

Usage Example :

```
private void yourTextBasedComponent_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   return YourTextBasedComponent.Text.Mask_IT('*', 2);
}
```

Note - 1 : Always Use `TextChanged` Event..With using `Text_Changed` event ( or similar event which implemented with your component) you can block unwanted results..as an example if someone try to copy-paste an unwanted string, then your `Key-Up` or `KeyDown` events won't work because of their listening characteristics..but `Text_Changed` always work when the text is changed;)

Note - 2 : In Method There is a parameter named "AllowedCharCount"..This is for "Leave the last (n) chars as not masked"